# Agrupar e somar arrays dinamicos PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estou criando um carrinho de compras e gravo na sessão os id's dos produtos da seguinte forma:

```
array(
    636 => 1,
    637 => 2
);
```

Onde o 636 e 637 referem-se ao ID do produto e o valor seria a quantidade dos mesmos. Até ai tudo certo.

A questão é quando preciso atualizar a quantidade de um deles. Por exemplo o cliente quer acrescentar +1 do código 636 e 1 do código 638.

Como faço para atualizar este array somando a quantidade do 636 e acrescentando ainda o 638 neste mesmo array.

O mesmo deveria ficar assim:

```
array(
    636 => 2,
    637 => 2,
    638 => 1
);
```

Vi algumas soluções aqui porém nenhuma que funcionasse nesta questão.

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Depende como recebe a requisição.. Não está clara essa parte, como recebe a ação para adicionar ou atualizar o cart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso deve resolver:

```
$lista = array(
    636 => 1,
    637 => 2
);

$novosItens = array(
    636 => 1,
    638 => 1
);

foreach ($novosItens as $produto => $quantidade) {
    if (array_key_exists($produto, $lista)) {
        $lista[$produto] += $quantidade;
    } else {
        $lista[$produto] = $quantidade;
    }
}

print_r($lista);

/*
Array ( 
    [636] => 2 
    [637] => 2 
    [638] => 1 
)
*/
```

Comment: Perfeito @andre-cardoso, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Para resolver este problema criei uma função chamada sumArray:

```
 function sumArray(array $old, array $new)
 {

    foreach ($new as $key => $value) {
        if (array_key_exists($key, $old)) {     
            $old[$key] += $value;
        } else {
            $old[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    return $old;
}

$oldValues = array(
    636 => 1,
    637 => 2
);

$newValues = array(
    636 => 1,
    638 => 1
);

$data = sumArray($oldValues, $newValues);

/* Saída
Array (
    [636] => 2
    [637] => 2
    [638] => 1
)
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Quando for atualizar verifique se o índice existe no array, se sim você soma com valor atual, se não você cria.

```
// carrinho   
$lista = array(
    636 => 1,
    637 => 2
);

// ação
$qtd = 1;
$produtoId = 637;
$lista[$produtoId] = $qdt + (isset($lista[$produtoId]) ? $lista[$produtoId] : 0);
```